# ZegoExpressManager joinRoom - Parameter is Array Type

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameters

I'm **noob** and need your **Help**

i have this Function here:

```
async function joinRoom() {
      const tokenObj = await generateToken();
      await ZegoExpressManager.shared.joinRoom(config.roomID, tokenObj.token, {
        userID: config.userID,
        userName: config.userName,
        
      });
```

I need now to **Set the last Parameter** to this:

```
[ZegoMediaOptions.AutoPlayAudio, ZegoMediaOptions.PublishLocalAudio]
```

This is what i tried:

```
async function joinRoom() {
      const tokenObj = await generateToken();
      await ZegoExpressManager.shared.joinRoom(config.roomID, tokenObj.token, {
        userID: config.userID,
        userName: config.userName,
        AutoPlayAudio: 1,
        PublishLocalAudio: 4, 
        
      });
```

And it not works...
The **support of the API** told me: **The Last Parameter is an ArrayType**

Please teach me ))

Comment: Is that really java? looks like JavaScript to me (Which is a completely different language than java despite the similar name).

Comment: Oh sorry let me Edit

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you look at the TypeScript definition of [joinRoom](https://github.com/ZEGOCLOUD/easy_example_web/blob/main/src/ZegoExpressManager.ts#L75) function:

```ts
joinRoom(
    roomID: string,
    token: string,
    user: ZegoUser,
    options?: ZegoMediaOptions[]
  ): Promise<boolean>
```

You can conclude that:

- joinRoom takes 4 arguments
- options argument is optional (you don't need to specify it)
- options takes an array

I never used the API, but my attempt would be:

```js
await ZegoExpressManager.shared.joinRoom(
  config.roomID, 
  tokenObj.token, 
  {
    userID: config.userID,
    userName: config.userName
  },
  [ZegoMediaOptions.AutoPlayAudio, ZegoMediaOptions.PublishLocalAudio]
);
```

Comment: Omg, your right

Comment: Bro i did it but u need to wait, because im New here and my upvotest doesnt count till i get lvl 15 or something like that ))